# Conditional Formatting in Excel comparing values in cell over multiple rows

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns Marks and Expected Marks, using conditional formatting i want to highlight all cells where marks are greater than expected marks in the same row. How to apply such conditional formatting over multiple rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select marks cells, in conditional formatting choose "Format only cells that contains", then choose "Greater than" and choose first cell from expected marks column.

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works for the first row, however B3, needs to be compared to A3, B5 needs to be compared to A5, and so on, this does not work in those scenarios

Comment: It works for all rows if you selected B column, it will automatically adjust a2 to a3 and so on. Just be sure that formula is =A2 ant not =$A$2